# String index out of range error Python for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing, error-handling, break

My simple brute force password program works perfectly fine so far, but whenever it runs it always prints out the last last and has the String Index out of range error. Everything works fine, and i get the output I want but I still get the error whenever the while loop closes and the program stops running.

```
userpassword = raw_input("Enter a password: ")

k = 0
cyclenumb = 0
newpasswordlist=[]

lowercaselist=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
uppercaselist=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
numberslist=["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]
symbolslist=["~", "`", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "-", "_", "=", "+", "{", "[", "]", "}", "|", "\ ", ";", ":", "'", '"', ",", "<", ".", ">", "/", "?", " "]  

while cyclenumb <= 10000:

    for x in userpassword[k]:
        for z in lowercaselist:
            if x in z:
                newpasswordlist.append(z)
                k +=1
                print newpasswordlist
            if x is not z:
                for x in userpassword[k]:
                    for z in uppercaselist:
                        if x in z:
                            newpasswordlist.append(z)
                            k +=1
                            print newpasswordlist
                        if x is not z:
                            for x in userpassword[k]:
                                for z in numberslist:
                                    if x in z:
                                        newpasswordlist.append(z)
                                        k +=1
                                        print newpasswordlist
                                if x is not z:
                                    for x in userpassword[k]:
                                        for z in symbolslist:
                                            if x in z:
                                                newpasswordlist.append(z)
                                                k +=1
                                                print newpasswordlist

    if userpassword == newpasswordlist:
        break

print newpasswordlist
print "Here is your original password " + userpassword
```

Please help me with this simple error.

Comment: What is the "last last"?  What line does the error refer to?

Comment: line 28, for x in userpassword[k]

Comment: but it changes to other lines that starts for loops, for example line 35. I believe it chooses which line to state the where the error is based on the last character of userpassword

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in this code that even attempts to detect when `k` is greater than or equal to the length of `userpassword`.  You could, for example, check for this whenever `k` gets incremented; if it is too big, break out of the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is not very good. You are doing `for x in userpassword[k]`, which is pointless, because `userpassword[k]` is always single letter. Next, You compare `userpassword` (which is string) with `newpasswordlist` (which is list). So, I recommend You redefine algorithm You use for this task.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the use of *k* altogether by doing something like this. I'm also not sure of why you have the while loop, but here was my fix to your problem.

```
for x in userpassword:
    for z in lowercaselist:
        if x is z:
            newpasswordlist.append(z)
            print newpasswordlist
            continue
        if x is not z:
            for z in uppercaselist:
                if x is z:
                    newpasswordlist.append(z)
                    print newpasswordlist
                    break
                if x is not z:
                    for z in numberslist:
                        if x is z:
                            newpasswordlist.append(z)
                            print newpasswordlist
                            break
                        if x is not z:
                            for z in symbolslist:
                                if x is z:
                                    newpasswordlist.append(z)
                                    print newpasswordlist
                                    break
    if userpassword is newpasswordlist:
         break
```